# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')

Tags: node.js, reactjs

****Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')****

```
const UserProfile =()=> {
      const [userProfile,setProfile]=useState(null)
      const {state,dispatch}=useContext(UserContext)
      const {userid} = useParams()
      useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(`/user/${userid}`,{
          headers:{
            "Authorization":'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem("jwt")
          }
        }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then(result=>{
         console.log(result) 
         setProfile(result)
        })
      },[])
      return( 
      <div>
          <div className='containerdetail'>
            <div>
              
            <div className='infocontainer'>
              <h2>{userProfile.user.name}</h2>
              <h4>{userProfile.user.email}</h4>
             
            </div>
           
          </div>
          <div className='imagecontainer'>
            {userProfile?.length === 0 && (
              <div>
                <span>Loading, Please Wait</span>
              </div>
            )}
            {
              userProfile?.length > 0 && UserProfile?.map(item=>{
                return(
                  <div className='img-wrapper'>
                    <img key={item._id} className='image' src={item.photo} alt="blank"/>
                  </div>
                  )
              })
            }
   
            </div>
      </div>);
    };
    
    export default UserProfile;
```

I keep getting  Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user'), it runs when I refresh it sometimes but again, when I refresh it later it provides same error

This is what I get when I console.log (result)

```
"user": {
    "_id": "61ef7dee4bcf690042259659",
    "name": "xyz",
    "email": "xyz@xyz.com",
    "__v": 0
},
```

I mapped the result into setProfile and extracted. name and email. can someone tell me what's the error here?

Comment: you need to guard against the case where it doesn't exist i.e. your `setProfile` hasn't happened yet or is in progress.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen sorry didnt get you , can you please ellaborate

Comment: Your data is fetched in a useEffect, which runs _after_ the first render. On that first render your `userProfile` state variable is `null` so `userProfile.user` doesn't exist.

Comment: can you help me how to overcome this stituation, please

Comment: `if (!userProfile) { return null; }` before your JSX.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
const UserProfile = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('idle') // idle || loading || loaded || error
  const [userProfile, setProfile] = useState(null)
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext)
  const { userid } = useParams()
  useEffect(() => {
    setStatus('loading')
    fetch(`/user/${userid}`, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("jwt")
      }
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
        setProfile(result)
        setStatus('loaded')
      })
      .catch(err => setStatus('error'))
  }, [])

  if (status === 'idle' || status === 'loading') {
    return (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    )
  } else if (status === 'loaded') {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='containerdetail'>
          <div>
            <div className='infocontainer'>
              <h2>{userProfile.user.name}</h2>
              <h4>{userProfile.user.email}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='imagecontainer'>
            <div className='img-wrapper'>
              <img key={userProfile._id} className='image' src={userProfile.photo} alt="blank" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else { //error
    return (
      <div>Error Laoding User Profile!</div>
    )
  }
};

export default UserProfile;
```

Comment: Posting an answer without an explanation doesn't really help. Please add some context on your answer.